# Dual polarization vs dual slant (+-45) polarization

Tags: antenna

Is “dual slant polarization” also called dual-polarized? Does it provide vertical and horizontal polarization at the same time?

Comment: Have you already read tutorial pages such as these: [Part 1](https://mimosa.co/white-papers/antenna-polarization) and [Part 2](https://mimosa.co/white-papers/antenna-polarization-2)?

Answer (score 0):

Slant is just two polarizations, usually at right angles to each other.  So H & V polarizations can just be thought of as a special case of two slant polarizations.

I usually see H&V used when those two polarizations align with the H&V (or X&Y, depending on the coordinate system being used) axis of a frame of reference, and slant left and slant right when those polarizations are rotated.  The amount of rotation is commonly 45 deg, but it doesn't have to be.

If being used simultaneously, the two polarizations combine, so that in the far field you see only a single polarization that's a combination of the two.  At the receive end, that signal can be separated by two orthogonally polarized antennas, or antenna elements, into its constituent components.

Comment: Minor suggestion, first sentence: "Slant is just two polarization" should be "**Dual** slant".